# Use of the executeUpdate(String) method is not supported on this type of statement

Tags: java, android, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

```
PreparedStatement pstmt;
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    String squery = "insert into response(seat_no,question_no,ans_opt,screenshot) values(?,?,?,?)";
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(squery);
    pstmt.setString(1, cd.getseat());// This is for fetching seat number
    pstmt.setInt(2, i + 1);// This is for question number
    pstmt.setString(3, res[i].getAns());//This is for rensponse answer
    pstmt.setBytes(4, res[i].getScshot());// This is for screenshot byte array
    int num = pstmt.executeUpdate(squery);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(num), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

My Table in Sql server 2008 R2

Response Table

seat_no nVARCHAR(MAX);

question_no int;

ans_opt text;

screenshot image;

It says error when inserting like "Use of the executeUpdate(String) method is not supported on this type of statement"

Answer (score 3):

You've already specified the SQL when you prepared the statement:

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(squery);
```

You shouldn't then use `Statement.executeUpdate(String)` - instead, just use the parameterless `executeUpdate()` method:

```
int num = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

You might also want to consider reusing the same `PreparedStatement` for several calls, or using `addBatch` to execute multiple updates in one go.

Comment: Thanks Sir, You made my day my college project can now proceed